# Yii define invalid strings

Tags: php, string, validation, frameworks, yii

I am creating register system in Yii and I want that people were unable to register usernames like admin, administrator, superuser, moderator... So can you tell me how to do this? It will be better if there will be some opportunity to list this invalid names in array in form validation.

so, any help?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom validator for your registration form. The easiest way to do that is inside your model like this:

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
       array('username', 'my_validation_rule'),
    );
}

public function my_validation_rule($attribute) {
    $restricted_usernames = array('admin', 'root', 'superuser');
    if(in_array($this->$attribute, $restricted_usernames))
        $this->addError($attribute, 'This username is restricted!');
}
```

Comment: There's a built-in way to do that, using [`CRangeValidator`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CRangeValidator). Rule for it would look like this: `array('username', 'in', 'range' => array('admin', 'root', 'superuser'))`. (Although your solution is better, since it can be trivially extended to handle case sensitivity, `CRangeValidator` cannot.)